# Why does this "if" condition not break the loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a `for` loop with a conditional block that breaks the loop.

However, the loop never breaks.
This is my code:

```
for($counter=1;$counter>5 or $counter<=100;$counter*=2){

    echo $counter."<br>";
    if($counter==500){
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output look like?  Is it: 1 2 4 8 16...? If so, it'll never reach 500, but will skip right over it. So that's why it doesn't break.

Comment: Your continuation condition is essentially "true," as $counter logically has to be either > 5 or <= 100 or both. Under what circumstance do you want your loop to end?

Answer (score 2):

Because counter is never exactly 500. It will be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, ...

You probably want

```
if($counter>=500){
  break;
}
```

but I can't say for sure because I have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `$counter` will never be equal to 500 to satisfy the conditional if statement. You should change

```php
if($counter==500){
  break;
}
```

to

```php
if($counter>500){
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your break logic is wrong:

loop calculation => next value

```
1 => 1
1*2 => 2
2*2 => 4
4*2 => 8
8*2 => 16
16*2 => 32
32*2 => 64
62*2 => 128
128*2 => 256
256*2 => 512
512*2 => 1024
```

To break your loop change your

```
if($counter==500){
  break;
}
```

to

```
if($counter>500){
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, `$counter` will never be exactly 500, as it goes through the powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, etc).

The fix for this is simple: you use `>500` instead of `==500`

---

However, in addition, this code has general issues that I would like to point out to you, since it seems like you are learning to program.

Your **for** loop condition is `$counter > 5 or $counter <=100`. This covers all numbers, since all numbers are either more than 5 or less than (or equal to) 100.

This means that the **for** loop will run forever as the check will always be true.

You then have a manual check after each loop that checks if `$counter` is greater than 500. This can be moved up to the condition with minor tinkering, as the **for** loop checks the condition after every loop (same as your manual check).

The new condition becomes "the old condition AND NOT the manual condition" (boolean AND). Since the old condition is always true, the new condition becomes `TRUE & !$counter > 500`, which is the same as `$counter <= 500`.

---

I hope I've explained this well enough but if you have any confusion just ask me in the comments to this answer and I'll be happy to clear anything up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, this should produce what you want.

```
for($counter = 8; $counter <= 500; $counter *= 2) {
    echo $counter."<br>";
}
```

This will echo 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 and exit the loop because the next value, 512, will not be <= 500.

Another option, if you need to start at 1, would be:

```
for($counter = 1; $counter <= 500; $counter *= 2) {
  if($counter < 6 ) {
    continue; // this will jump back to the start of the for loop
  } else {
    echo $counter."<br>";
  }
}
```

In your original code:
If you start with the $counter = 1, the values of 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, & 64 will all return true because of the <= 100 condition.
If you include the $counter > 5 condition, every value beyond 5 will be true (8, 16, 32, ...to infinity).
Since the counter doubles each time, it will never equal 500 (it will be 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024...) so the condition triggering the break will never happen.